# Eigenvectors of the square of an operator

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $V$ be a vector space and $D:V\rightarrow V$ be linear. Let $s$ be an eigenvector of $D^2$. Can we always express $s$ as a linear combination of eigenvectors of $D$? If not, what conditions might we require for this to be true?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can always do so if $D$ is diagonalizable invertible.

Otherwise, we have counterexamples like
$$
D=\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}
$$
Note that $D^2$ as the eigenvector $(0,1)$.

Comment: Actually what I wanted to ask is slightly different: if $V$ is infinite dimensional, $D$ is self-adjoint, and $s$ is an eigenvector of $D^2$ with eigenvalue in the range $[0,c^2]$, can we always decompose $s$ as a linear combination of eigenvectors of $D$  corresponding to eigenvalues in the range $[-c,c]$?

Comment: The answer is no. At the very least, the finite dimensional counterexample applies.

Comment: Does it help if $D$ is self-adjoint?

Comment: Yes, then the spectral theorem applies.

Comment: I see, thank you. Which statement of the spectral theorem should I look at?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how the $[0,c^2]$ would fit into the spectral theorem.

Comment: Oh, if $c\neq0$, this might always be true. It's the $c=0$ case that's a bit strange.